# Stanford CoreNLP - load annotated file instead annotate method

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, pretty-print

I obtained a file with "prettyprint" method and i would load it instead use "annotate" method. But i can't find the method to use.
I working with stanford-corenlp-3.9.0 and the api.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the pipeline on a file once, and then save the results and load them from file later, you need to use the protobuf serialization functionality we provide.  We don't have any methods that load `json` or `text` and build an annotation from it.

```
ProtobufAnnotationSerializer serializer = new ProtobufAnnotationSerializer();
File inputFile = ...;
Annotation ann = serializer.readUndelimited(inputFile);
```

If you run the pipeline you can have it output serialized files with `-outputFormat serialized` and `-serializer edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.ProtobufAnnotationSerializer`

Every file it processes will be a protocol buffer representing the annotation for that file.